# Rename "blogs" tag to "blog"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have no idea why we need the [blogs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/blogs) tag to be plural.

We have [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/terminal), not [terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/terminals).
We have [shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell), not [shells](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shells).
We have [scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanner), not [scanners](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanners).

For consistency's sake, can we please make the tag singular?

Comment: 15,500 reputation, just rename it yourself you most likely have permission.

Comment: @Star it's too similar to the existing tag. Only moderators can create synonyms.

Comment: @NathanOsman there are not enough non-mod users who can (only 4), so, yep, might as well get a mod to do it. :D

Comment: I was thinking that too, no need to hate or whatever.

Comment: I'm not even sure we need a tags for "blogs"... whose blog? In fact, no new question since 2013... just let this tag die along with all those questions.

Comment: We have a blog tag? What does that even have to do with Ubuntu? (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: Lots of users use Ubuntu to host their blogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Done.